# Unable to see all flag options

Tags: support, flags

I wanted to flag [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196060/updating-data-from-handheld-device-to-sql-server-asp-net) question as too broad, but I could only see 3 options as below

[image]

But after some time I saw this question was put on hold for same reason(broad). So why I could not see that option when I wanted to flag it?

Comment: By the time you opened the dialog, the question was already closed. Since you can't close a closed question, you only got the options that you would potentially need for an already-closed question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you loaded the question (16:04:58 UTC), it was still open. But by the time you opened the flag dialog (16:13:10 UTC) the question had already been closed (at  16:12:51 UTC - a scant 19 seconds earlier).

So the flag option was unavailable because it would've been meaningless.

Blame George for being so quick...

Answer (score 1):

The question is already closed. There is no need to flag it as too broad at that point, so the option is removed.

The remaining three options are for more severe flags and all carry potential penalties against the owner.

Comment: when I checked this at first, It was not closed.

Comment: @ChaitanyaGadkari, I believe Shog9 [answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294112/189134) that particular question for you. It was closed by the time you opened the flag dialog.