# Flag Answer doesn't show all options?

Tags: support, flags, answers

I found an answer that I wanted to flag as NAA (although, now that I think about it, it probably isn't and just deserves my downvote instead), but when I tried to flag it, the option wasn't there! In fact, there was only one option:

[image: Flag Answer - Missing Most Flags]

I thought that was strange, so I opened the dialog on another answer in the same question:

[image: Flag Answer - All Flags Shown]

The dialog for this other answer worked correctly, with all of the possible flags listed.

Why are they not shown on the first answer?

(I will preemptively defend against closing as a duplicate of question such as [Unable to see all flag options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294110/unable-to-see-all-flag-options) by saying that that question talks about flagging *questions*, and the answer doesn't apply here.)

Comment: Possibly it's already been deleted.

Comment: The answer to your linked question is similar here, most likely: The answer was _deleted_ by the time you opened the dialog, and therefore you only have the "Other" option available. If you haven't yet, try refreshing that page.

Comment: *"now that I think about it, it probably isn't"* that was good thinking. If you'd been able to flag as NAA, it would have almost certainly been declined.

Comment: @CodeCaster Dang... I didn't find that when searching for duplicates. I have to agree with that though.

Comment: Probably because this particular flag option has been renamed recently. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that's almost always due to the answer itself being deleted (by the user, through review, or by a moderator) after you've loaded the page but before you've brought up the flag menu. The flag menu will respond to the state of the post at that moment, and only present relevant options.

I usually recommend forcing a refresh of the page at that point to verify that the post has already been handled. If so, you don't need to worry about flagging it.