# Flagging own undeleted answer doesn't show all options

Tags: support, flags

I gave [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421426/running-tests-on-vm-does-not-work-unless-window-is-open/47429284#47429284) to a question and I wanted to ask for someone to improve the formatting, because apparently, even though I wrapped the registry code as sample code, it's still displayed as if it's not formatted.

However, as can be seen in this screenshot, after I click on the flag button I only have one choice
[image: answer screenshot]

Anyone knows why? It's not a duplicate after [Flag Answer doesn't show all options?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300563/flag-answer-doesnt-show-all-options), because neither the question nor is my answer deleted.

Comment: No moderator is going to do that edit for you

Comment: You do not raise flag because you _"need help with formatting"_.

Comment: I seem to get downvotes to this question due to the reason I ask for the feature. The point of my question was why don't I see all options? Did the system foresee I'm going to use them wrong? :)

Comment: People might go off because you use an example where a flag would not be appropiate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I wanted to ask for someone to improve the formatting, because apparently, even though I wrapped the registry code as sample code, it's still displayed as if it's not formatted.

You shouldn't be using flags for this. Any one who views it can suggest an edit or ones with edit privileges can correct it. (You need to give four additional spaces to the code if it is a part of numbering/bullet list)

Secondly, the other flags being:

- Very Low Quality
- Not An Answer
- Spam
- Rude or Abusive
- Close (This one is shown on questions)

etc.. are not visible **because it is your own answer**. Raising those flags doesnt make sense. You can and should correct the problem in your own post or delete it if they require the above flags.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, now that I see the other options.

Comment: Perhaps they should be displayed but disabled with a reason shown when hovering over them.

Comment: @Adelin don't see the point of having additional disabled options. If anyone else is confused they can be redirected to your question :)